# How click a link on one page and have a specific filter option chosen on linked page?

Tags: javascript, url, filter, hyperlink

I've been searching all over the internet for this one, and either the suggestions don't seem to apply, or I'm not using the right terminology to describe what I'm wanting to do, so nothing comes up.

Here's the long story:

On our Home Page, we have a section called "Industries".  In this section, there are a few choices, "Government", "Manufacturing", "Energy", "Health Care", etc.  A visitor to our site can click on one of those choices and it will take them to our Product Filter Page.  I would like to have it so that if they clicked on "Manufacturing", that the option would already be chosen on the Product Filter Page, so they only see our products that are available for the Manufacturing Industry.

I am not a coder by any means, but I have been able to take code that I find on forums, and slightly modify it to make it work on our site, to achieve other functionality that we've wanted. But I can't seem to find anything that makes any sense to me that would allow me to modify it to work for us in this case.

Here is the code that makes up the drop-down list on the Product Filter Page, that relates to the Industries that could be chosen:

```
<div class="dv-dropdown">
  <div class="caption">All Industries</div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item df-button">All Industries</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-retail">Retail</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-construction">Construction</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-warehousing">Warehousing</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-manufacturing">Manufacturing</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-government">Government</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-energy">Energy</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-automotive">Automotive</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-printing">Printing</div>
    <div class="item df-button dfc-healthcare">Health Care</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what exactly I could include for the Javascript that is on the page, as it is from a purchasable plugin - Divi Filter - and I'm pretty sure that this will need custom script to get it to work.

This is my first post, so please let me know if you need anything else from me.  I am currently in the process of creating the site, so it's not exactly live. Thus, if there's any reference to URL links, please just make use of a generic site example, and I can replace it as needed.

Thank you all in advance for your help, and I will do my best to respond to any questions you may have, but please keep in mind my inexperience with coding.

EDIT:
Here is a snippet of the Javascript used for filtering the classes:

```
var activeClasses = [];

jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('.dv-dropdown .df-button').on('click', function() {

    // get number of dropdown
    var dvIndex = jQuery(this).closest(".dv-dropdown").index(".dv-dropdown");

    /* remove class */
    if (activeClasses[dvIndex] != "") {
      jQuery('.dv-dropdown:not(:eq(' + dvIndex + ')) .df-button').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass(activeClasses[dvIndex]);
      });
      activeClasses[dvIndex] = "";
    }

    // get button classes
    var filterClasses = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

    // remove all classes except dfc-
    filterClasses = jQuery.grep(filterClasses, function(element) {
      return element.indexOf("dfc-") === 0;
    });

    // remove all other active classes from button 
    jQuery.each(activeClasses, function( index, value ) {
      if(index !== dvIndex) {
        filterClasses = filterClasses.filter(e => e !== activeClasses[index]);
      }
    });

    if (filterClasses[0] != undefined) { // undefined if you click on all, because no class then just remove

      activeClasses[dvIndex] = filterClasses[0];

      jQuery('.dv-dropdown:not(:eq(' + dvIndex + ')) .df-button').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass(activeClasses[dvIndex]);
      });
    }

    // add active button class dv-activebutton
    jQuery.each(activeClasses, function( index, value ) {
      // remove classes 
      jQuery(".dv-dropdown:eq(" + index + ") .df-button").removeClass("dv-activebutton");

      // add it to active element
      if(value !== "" && typeof value !== 'undefined') {
        jQuery(".dv-dropdown:eq(" + index + ") .df-button." + value).addClass("dv-activebutton");
      }
      else {
        jQuery(".dv-dropdown:eq(" + index + ") .df-button.dv-all").addClass("dv-activebutton");
```

Here is a snippet of the Javascript used for the dropdowns

```
jQuery(function() {
  
    /* toggle open class */
  jQuery('.dv-dropdown > .caption').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    jQuery('.dv-dropdown > .caption').not(this).parent().removeClass('open');
  });
  
  /* make item active element and add to caption */
  jQuery('.dv-dropdown > .list > .item').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected').parent().parent().removeClass('open').children('.caption').text( jQuery(this).text() );
  });
  
    /* close dropdown if Esc is clicked on keyboard */
  jQuery(document).on('keyup', function(evt) {
    if ( (evt.keyCode || evt.which) === 27 ) {
      jQuery('.dv-dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
    /* on click remove, close dropdown */
  jQuery(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    if ( jQuery(evt.target).closest(".dv-dropdown > .caption").length === 0 ) {
      jQuery('.dv-dropdown').removeClass('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is add a query string to the URL that the link takes you to. So if you clicked "Manufacturing" on the first page, it would append something like `"?industry=Manufacturing"` to the end of the URL for the product filter page. Then, on the product filter page you would write a javascript function get the value of the query param (`window.location.search`). This query param would be the "value" chosen for the dropdown.

Are you using any javascript frameworks? A snippet of the code you have for the product filter page would be helpful.

Comment: Added Javascript code snippets to the main post.